# Bootstrap refresh icon with text on Submit button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a "Refresh" button on my page. For that I decided to use the bootstrap refresh-icon style. The icon appears on my button but it does not leave much room for the text "Refresh". Here is the code and Fiddle...

```
<input class="icon-refresh" type="submit" value="Refresh" name="Test"> </input>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jjaleel/kVHbV/339/

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can expand the button width so it shows both the refresh icon and the text?

Thanks.

Comment: use a [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tag instead, it's what they were made for :)

Comment: Can't we specify width?

Answer (score 12):

You could use a [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tag instead, they were made to be styled with much more control than an input.

Here's how I would use one with the latest bootstrap..

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Refresh</button>
```

Comment: Why did someone downvote this and upvote mine? it's the same as mine (practically) and uses the framework more properly.

Comment: @Faust It's one of those phantom downvotes :) I don't mind though as long as the OP gets an answer hey :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in my case I am using Richfaces Command Button (http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_commandButton.html), so the tag is actually generated. I do not believe I can change it. Is there anyway I can do what I asked in my original question using the input tag?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `<button>`, with the submit action, instead:

```
<button type="submit"><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Test</button>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVHbV/342/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but please see my comments to Dale.

Answer (score 1):

Put the refresh icon in a span inside a button:

```
<button type="submit" value="Refresh" name="Test"><span class="icon-refresh"></span> </button>
```

**update** (based on OP comment)

Without being able to change the markup at all, this is tough. To get rid of the "Refresh" text, set the text-color to `transparent`. For sizing, set display to inline-block and fix height and width to 20px.

```
input{
    display:inline-block;
    color:transparent;
    height:20px !important;
    width:20px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but please see my comments to Dale.